# Mapping One to Many from Different Table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

**Current setup:**

```
Entity A:

fieldA; 
@OneToMany(mappedBy="fieldA")
List<B> Bs;


Entity B:

fieldA;
fieldB;
fieldX;
```

Entity A maps to Table A, and Entity B maps to Table B. fieldA is the primary key to Table A, and fieldA & fieldB make up the composite primary keys to Table B

The problem is, when we load A with this setup is we get back thousands of objects in List of Bs, while we only care about what the value of fieldB is in entity B. To save memory, we want to have List of FieldBs rather than List of Bs in entity A and completely get rid of the entity B class.

So looking more like this

```
Entity A:

fieldA; 
List<fieldB> Bs;
```

Is this possible? Well I certainly hope so but I am not sure exactly how. 
Will the @SecondaryTable with an annotation like:

```
@SecondaryTables({
    @SecondaryTable(name="Table B", pkJoinColumns={
            @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="fieldA")}
    )
```

with

```
@JoinColumn(name="fieldB", table="Table B")
List<fieldB> Bs;
```

do the trick? The problem is I still want to have that @OneToMany relationship mapping so I think I need to include that somewhere as well.

Just to be clear I want to get rid of class B from my Java code and move the fieldB to class A maintaining the @OneToMany relationship. But still be able to read List and have it save back to table B.

Answer (score 0):

This is how Hibernate works. It will by default load all properties of objects(apart from collections which are lazy loaded). 
Is your app so limited in memory that you want to optimize at this level?

What you're asking is only possible only if you write wrapper classes which you populate with costum HQL.

These are some things you can do:

- Use [lazy property fetching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties) to ignore unwanted fields.
- Use custom HQL query which returns a custom object with only your
  required    fields. [Link](http://learningviacode.blogspot.com/2012/10/hql-and-new-keyword.html)

Comment: Are you saying its impossible to do this without writing a wrapper class? FieldB is just a primitive. It would be much more beneficial memory-wise to get back fieldB rather than even wrapper class of fieldB. We are getting hundreds of thousands of objects back in that list so memory is a concern.

Comment: Just to be clear I want to get rid of class B from my Java code and move the fieldB to class A maintaining the @OneToMany relationship. But still be able to read List<fieldB> and have it save back to table B.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying. If you want to work at that level of optimization avoid Hibernate altogether! Moreover, it's not a good idea to load hundreds of thousands of records in memory, you usually use pagination for such cases.

Comment: I find it almost hard to believe that this is not possible. We can get any property from another table inside a different entity by the use of SecondaryTable annotation (no wrapper required). The only difference here is we want a list of the property in a @OneToMany relationship.